# Working of getchar and putchar or example in The C language 2nd Edition

Tags: c

CODE 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
     int c;
     while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
     putchar(c);
     return 0;
  }
```

CODE 2:

```
   #include<stdio.h>

    main( )
    {
        int c,d;
        c=getchar();
        d=getchar();
        putchar(c);
        putchar(d);
   }
```

1) If
          Input : bo
          Output : bo
   I got to know this in 2nd program that it stores both in variables c and d but where does it stores them in 1st program.

2)Pl. explain the working of first program why it repeats any word despite of its length that is more than one character.

3) From book i got to know that EOF is encountered whenever I enter or there is some error but even if I press enter this program doesn't stops but it prints nextline character again.

Comment: It's a `while` loop. The same variable `c` stores different characters in each iteration.

Comment: To input `EOF`, try Ctrl + Z on Windows, or Ctrl + D on Unix families.

Comment: @YuHao Did you mean Ctrl+D on Unix?

Comment: @devnull Oops, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

For question one, it stores *them* in `c` (but only one at a time). The code, better indented, is:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
```

so you can see that, for *each* character input into `c`, it outputs it as well. Keep in mind that syntax is the short form for:

```
c = getchar();
while (c != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
}
```

so you can see each iteration of the loop gets the next character.

---

The second question, I assume you're asking why it works for any length input. That's because it doesn't care about the length. It's simply storing and echoing each individual character.

You could give it a billion characters if you like.

---

As to the third, you get back EOF for an error or *end of file* (CTRL-Z at the start of a line for Windows, *usually* CTRL-D under UNIX-like operating systems, unless you have some weird terminal characteristics set up).

If you were only interested in a *line,* you could use something like:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    putchar(c);
putchar ('\n');
```

Comment: Hi pax, even i don't get the second part. I have theree questions in my mind:

Comment: 1 ) I assume when i input a character 'c' , it checks for EOF and then it should immediately print 'c', but it doesn't. why does it wait till i hit the ENTER? 2) as you said " because it doesn't care about the length. It's simply storing and echoing each individual character." where does it store all the characters and outputs after we press Enter, when it can only store one character. 3) if i don't put putchar() inside the while loop it only prints first character. where are the other stored characters then?

Comment: @RaJ, all those questions are basically answered with the phrase 'input buffering'. In cooked mode (rather than raw mode), line based buffering is happening inside the lower level so that no characters are delivered to your code until you press ENTER. The lower levels are responsible for said buffering although I don't think this level of detail is mandated by the C standard itself.

Comment: OK great thanks. This is what I needed to know. Now I am getting things. Well, even if it's not mandated, you gotta know every single thing to do your own thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Reads the value from stdin until it encounters EOF(End Of File). So the same variable c stores different values read in different iterations.

In the second example only two variable ( of char type ) are there so it can read and store only two characters.